# QGIS categorized legend show only with data

Tags: qgis, style, categorized-renderer

I generate maps from CSV to which I apply a style sheet.

In the stylesheet defines the set of items I may encounter.

But in most csv, there are not all the elements defined in style.

So I find myself with times 10 points of the same type on the map, but with a legend of 50 categories.

How to display the categories that are present on the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button you want is called "Filter legend by map content." Here's what it looks like in the main QGIS window:

[image]

Here's what it looks like in the print composer:
[image]